# Load and unload multiple components in a sidebar using Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a page where a user is building up an order for a customer. At various stages of the order they may get to a point where they need to add something else. For example, when selecting an address for the customer the customer may have a new address that needs adding, or an existing address may need editing.

I want to be able to load small components on the fly in a right hand sidebar, but there could be any number of them, so I can't just have something like

```
{{outlet 'right-hand-bar'}}
```

For example the user may have clicked to add an address, but then may also click a product in the order and I would want to show another component with details on the product, below the add address component. I guess it is kind of like master detail concept, but detail can contain multiple distinct details.

It doesn't feel right to just have a number of outlet's and use the next one available i.e.

```
{{outlet 'right-hand-bar1'}}
{{outlet 'right-hand-bar2'}}
...
```

Is there a way to do this in Ember CLI? X number of components in a single outlet?

**Edit**

I am considering a concept involving creating a sideBar component with a main div

```
<div class='side-bar-load-area'></div>
```

and then having a loadComponent action in the sideBar component that takes the name of the component to load.

Not sure how I could load a component by name? I've seen this for a controller:

```
var comp = App.FooBarComponent.create();
comp.appendTo('#someArea');
```

and

```
this.controllerFor('someName');
```

So ideally would want to combine this and get it working for my sub components?

And also give the sidebar a closeComponent action that a given component could call to unload itself, for an outlet you would do

```
closeOutlet: function() {
  return this.disconnectOutlet({
    outlet: 'modal',
    parentView: 'application'
  });
}
```

So again just looking to translate this to work for unloading a component in the DOM, not in a outlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are running Ember 1.11+, you can use the new [component helper](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_component-helper)

Basically, you could do something along the lines of:

**templates/main_view.hbs**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  {{#each componentNames as |componentName|}}
    {{component componentName}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

and your buttons to create said components in:

**templates/main_view.hbs**

```
<button {{action "addAddress"}}>New address</button>
```

and the actions themselves in your controller:

**controllers/main_view.js**

```
actions: {
  addAddress: function() {
    var controller = this;
    var componentNames = controller.get("componentNames");
    componentNames.pushObject("address");
  }
}
```

Comment: Such a clean answer, works perfectly accept ember cli won't build if I leave the |'s around componentNames in the template, so I had to omit those.

Comment: If I wanted to have the sidebar in my application template rather than the main_view template then I can handle the addAddress action in my application route and push to componentNames there - is it ok in Ember to be storing componentNames in my application controller and accessing the application controller from my application route with var controller = this.controllerFor('application')?

Comment: about the |'s, I got mixed up. should be 'as' to use the pipes. updating answer.

Comment: as for the second question, since you're in the application route, you don't need this.controllerFor('application'). this.controller the controller for the route you are currently in. See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_controller

Comment: And yeah, go ahead and put code where it makes sense to you. It's software. When your understanding of the problem improves later, you can move things around. You'll probably think of some nicer abstraction or code organization later when you've had to do the same thing two or three times.